# Time Complexity of Finding All Possible Sub Array of an Array

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, time-complexity, powerset, binomial-theorem

As per the implementation of finding all possible sub-array from a given array as follows:

```
public class AllPossibleSubArray {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] arr = { 1, 2, 3 };
        List<List<Integer>> result = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int len = 0; len <= arr.length; len++) {
            if (len == 0) {
                result.add(new ArrayList<>());
            } else {
                for (int i = 0; i < arr.length - len + 1; i++) {
                    List<Integer> temp = new ArrayList<>();
                    for (int j = i; j < i + len; j++) {
                        temp.add(arr[j]);
                    }
                    result.add(temp);
                }
            }
        }

        result.forEach(System.out::println);
    }
```

As per my understanding that time complexity would be O(N^3) as there are three FOR loop.

But this problem is nothing but a power set i.e. finding all possible sub set from a given set. From various forum on web, time complexity of power set is 2^N (Binomial expansion) which is not same as O(N^3).

Am i missing some fundamental ?

Comment: Finding all possible sub-arrays is similar to get the power set of a given set, the only difference is, the array may has duplicate elements. Complexity should be O(2^n) where n is the length of the array. You can find tons of code in the net - how to generate a power set.

Answer (score 3):

> But this problem is nothing but a power set i.e. finding all possible sub set from a given set.

That's not correct.

The code that you've posted only finds *contiguous* subarrays, meaning the list of all elements from one index to another index.

The power set, by contrast, would also include *discontiguous* subsequences, meaning ones that include two elements without including all of the elements between them.

---

I should also note that there are only *O*(*n*<sup>2</sup>) subarrays, and if you find a different way to represent them, you can find them in *O*(*n*<sup>2</sup>) time rather than *O*(*n*<sup>3</sup>) time as the code that you've posted does. (Specifically, you need a representation that allows you to reuse the shared parts of the lists, rather than having to copy all required elements every time.) By contrast, if you stick with the representation in your code where each list has a distinct copy, finding all subsets would actually require *O*(*n*·2<sup>*n*</sup>) time, rather than just *O*(2<sup>*n*</sup>) time.

Answer (score 0):

Like the post above said the optimal time complexity for getting all the possible subarrays in an array is O(N^2). I would also like to point out that by definition a subarray is contiguous. check the following link for the definition of a sub array.
https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/subarraysubstring-vs-subsequence-and-programs-to-generate-them/amp/&ved=2ahUKEwiI8bOC9I76AhWRSvEDHWubCNAQFnoECAcQBQ&usg=AOvVaw1i1BkpzTxhLqu0mfVhCN87

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).